# Compactification of a noncompact regular level set of a map $\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, compactification

Consider a smooth function $f:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$, and a noncompact regular level subset $S=f^{-1}(c)$ for some regular value $c\in \Bbb R$. Then $S$ is a smooth hypersurface in $\Bbb R^n$, so it is an $(n-1)$-dimensional manifold. I want to show that $S$ is the interior of a compact manifold with boundary. I expect that for a sufficiently large closed disk $D\subset \Bbb R^n$ centered at the origin, the intersection $D\cap  S$ is such a manifold with boundary, but I'm not sure. Is this statement true? or is there another approach? Thanks in advance.

Edit: According to the comment, there is a counterexample even in the case $n=1$. Actually my siuation is the following: I want to show that for $S=\{z_1^{n_1}+z_2^{n_2} +z_3^{n_3}=c\}$ in $\Bbb C^3$ (where $n_1,n_2,n_3$ are positive integers and $c$ is a nonzero complex constant, $S\cap D$ is a manifold with boundary whose interior is homeomorphic to $S$, where $D$ is a sufficiently large closed disk $D^6$ in $\Bbb C^3$. I thought this result can be generalized to the situation described above, but I was wrong.

Comment: Hint: This is false even if $n=1$. An example is given by an elementary function you learned in high school.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks, I see with $f(x)=\sin x$ with $c=0$. I should make an edit for my concrete situation.

Comment: The revision indeed has positive answer. Are you familiar with Morse theory?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes I know some main theorems in Morse Theory.

Comment: Then argue that $||\cdot||^2$ has no large critical values on $S$. See for instance Milnor's book "Singular points of complex hypersurfaces", Appendix.